# Unexpected behaviour while extracting substrings from a string

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault, strtok

I'm trying to **print all substrings** contained in a big string, each of them **separated by a `'/'` character**. My function is not working as I would expect, but I don't get what's wrong with it. Here's the function I wrote:

```
void print_serial_list(char *serial_list) {
    char *iter = serial_list;
    while (*iter != '\0') { // Traverse the whole string
        char *tmp_fn;
        tmp_fn = strtok(iter,"/");
        printf("Extracted entry: '%s'\n", tmp_fn);
        iter = iter + sizeof(tmp_fn);
    }
}
```

#### Passing directly the string

If I run this function like this:

```
char *string = "Lorem.ipsum/dolor-sit-amet/consectetur/adipiscing.elit/";
printf("%s\n", string);
print_serial_list(string);
```

I get a segmentation fault:

```
Lorem.ipsum/dolor-sit-amet/consectetur/adipiscing.elit/
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

#### Using the `get_string()` function

On the other hand, if I run this:

```
char *string = get_string();
printf("%s\n", string);
print_serial_list(string);
```

I get the following output (still wrong):

```
Lorem.ipsum/dolor-sit-amet/consectetur/adipiscing.elit/
Extracted entry: 'Lorem.ipsum'
Extracted entry: 'sum'
Extracted entry: 'r-sit-amet'
Extracted entry: 'et'
Extracted entry: 'ctetur'
Extracted entry: 'dipiscing.elit'
Extracted entry: 'g.elit'
Extracted entry: '�'
Extracted entry: 'x[�V'
Extracted entry: 'x[�V'
```

#### Expectations

Just to be clear, I **would expect the output** to be in both cases:

```
Lorem.ipsum/dolor-sit-amet/consectetur/adipiscing.elit/
Extracted entry: 'Lorem.ipsum'
Extracted entry: 'dolor-sit-amet'
Extracted entry: 'consectetur'
Extracted entry: 'adipiscing.elit'
```

(***Note***: I hope the code of `get_string()` won't be necessary to understand the issue... I would like to try keeping the post not too long)

#### EDIT

Following a couple of advices in comments I edited the function in this way:

```
char *iter = serial_list;
bool first = true;
while (*iter != '\0') { // Traverse the whole string
    char *tmp_fn;
    if (first)
        tmp_fn = strtok(iter, "/");
    else
        tmp_fn = strtok(NULL, "/");
    size_t tmp_size = strlen(tmp_fn);
    printf("Extracted entry: '%s' - size = %zu\n", tmp_fn, tmp_size);
    iter = iter + tmp_size;
    first = false;
}
```

What I'm getting as output still has some problems, but is much more similar to what I wanted!

```
Lorem.ipsum/dolor-sit-amet/consectetur/adipiscing.elit/
Extracted entry: 'Lorem.ipsum' - size = 11
```

Comment: check `sizeof(tmp_fn)`..print it.

Comment: `sizeof` on a pointer gives you the size of *the pointer itself*, not what it points to. If you want to get the length of a string use [`strlen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen).

Comment: Furthermore, remember that [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) can return a null pointer, which you *must* check for. And you're really using [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) wrong.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks! You are totally right about the `strlen` thing. I changed it and I got only the first entry as result: `Extracted entry: 'Lorem.ipsum' - size = 11`...

Comment: Solved: I simply didn't have to increment the pointer to the char, as `strtok` i already taking care of it (so I just deleted `iter = iter + tmp_size;`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `If I run this function like this, I get a segmentation fault:`
>
> `char *string = "Lorem.ipsum/dolor-sit-amet/consectetur/adipiscing.elit/";`

Your program is having [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as it is trying to modify the string literal because you are passing the string literal to `strtok()`.

> char * strtok ( char * str, const char * delimiters );
>
> Split string into tokens
>
> A sequence of calls to this function split str into tokens, which are sequences of contiguous characters separated by any of the characters that are part of delimiters.

`string` is a pointer point to a string literal, whose contents can't be modified. And trying to modify them via the pointer is Undefined Behavior.

To resolve this you can simply do this:

```
char string[] = "Lorem.ipsum/dolor-sit-amet/consectetur/adipiscing.elit/";
           ^^
```

And in `print_serial_list()` function, you can do:

```
void print_serial_list(char *serial_list) {
    char *iter = serial_list;

    if (serial_list == NULL)
            return;

    char *tmp_fn = strtok(iter, "/");
    while (tmp_fn != NULL)
    {
            printf ("Extracted entry: '%s'\n", tmp_fn);
            tmp_fn = strtok(NULL, "/");
    }
}
```

The `print_serial_list()` output is (for `Lorem.ipsum/dolor-sit-amet/consectetur/adipiscing.elit/` input string):

```
Extracted entry: 'Lorem.ipsum'
Extracted entry: 'dolor-sit-amet'
Extracted entry: 'consectetur'
Extracted entry: 'adipiscing.elit'
```

A point to note here is the `print_serial_list()` will modify the string `string` as it is passing it to `strtok()`. If you don't want the input string to be modified after calling `print_serial_list()` function, make a copy of it in `print_serial_list()` function.

---

From [strtok](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok):

> Bugs
>   Be cautious when using these functions. If you do use them, note that:
>
> *These functions modify their first argument.
>
> *These functions cannot be used on constant strings.
>
> *The identity of the delimiting byte is lost.

Thanks @David C. Rankin for sharing these `strtok()` bugs in a comment.

Comment: I kind of like the first two bullet points under BUGS in the `man 3 strtok`, that really help drive the fact home, e.g. `"These functions modify their first argument."` and `"These functions cannot be used on constant strings."`